# Is there a way to catch warnings and log them into a file in django?

Tags: python, django, logging, pandas, warnings

I would like to know if there is a way to catch warnings in python and just log them into a file. I don't want to write my own warning, I simply want to catch the system warnings and log them.

Specifically I'm importing a csv with pandas, and in case a line is skipped, I would like to log the message: "Skipping line 25: expected 6 fields, saw 8"

Comment: Have you had a look at [Django's logging documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/)? You can set the level for to WARNING and specify a file for output

Comment: But that doesn't catch pandas warning, right? That would set my own warning, with my own message. Am I wrong?

Comment: [`logging.captureWarnings(True)`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) is the normal Python mechanism for making `warnings` warnings be logged, but I dunno how it interacts with Django's logging framework.